# Click on entire day block including events on fullcalender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```
<div id='calendar' style="min-height:330px"></div>

    LoadCalendar(calendarDisplayType,weekStartDay,weekendArr,editSetting,events);

    // Adding Events to the calendar
        function LoadCalendar(defaultViewtype,weekStartDay,weekEndArr,editSetting,events){
            //To reset the Calendar used destroy 
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                events:events,
                editable: true,
                defaultView: defaultViewtype,
                firstDay: weekStartDay,//Start day of Calender
                hiddenDays: weekEndArr, // Hide Days Non Working Days 
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                     if(event.icon){          
                        element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-"+event.icon+"'></i>");
                     }
                },
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view,start, end, allDay) {
                    viewTaskModal(date, jsEvent, view,start, end, allDay,editSetting);
                }

            });

        }

    function viewTaskModal(date, jsEvent, view,start, end, allDay,editSetting){
    //Code here to do stuff
        var cellYear = date.year();
        var cellMonth = date.month() + 1;
        var cellDay = date.date();
//............And few more code     
}
```

[image]

Now my problem is that on event with blue color i am not able to call viewTaskModal().
I am using **FULL calender** for this stuff to do.
I have tried this

```
eventClick: function(date, jsEvent, view,start, end, allDay){
                viewTaskModal(date, jsEvent, view,start, end, allDay,editSetting);
            }
```

But problem is i am not getting date if i tried this.

If any suggestion please provide it will helpfull for me

Comment: please provide fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The [`eventClick`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) function does not have the same parameters as the [`dayClick`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/). `eventClick` will return `calEvent` Object that contains a start property of the event clicked. Using the code below you can get the date of the event clicked. Here is a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpbgvW) showing this, try clicking both the day cell and the event.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert(calEvent.start);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me hoe to get the date on what event you have clicked through eventClick that is my question

Comment: The code I have provided does exactly what you are asking. Go to the codepen and click the event and the date of the event will be alerted. Or copy the code in my answer into your calendar and click an event, the date will be alerted.